# Mouse trail and slow response time

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm currently using my Dads computer and notice there is a huge delay and trail whenever moving the mouse. He is so used to it he doesn't realise it's there.

The problem is that he bought two 4k monitors:

> 27" 4K UHD (3840 x 2160) IPS DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI 4 ms Response Time
>   300 Nit Brightness

http://us-store.acer.com/s277hk-wmidpp-monitor

This is the setup he is running:

> 16384MB Ram
>
> AMD Radeon R9200

Let me know if you need anymore information, how do I troubleshoot this? is there software I can download to help me with the process

Comment: What is your Operating system?

Comment: He is using windows 10 @DavidPostill

Comment: [How to change the mouse speed in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000909.htm)

Comment: [Adjusting the Mouse Sensitivity in Windows 10](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Mouse-Sensitivity#Adjusting_the_Mouse_Sensitivity_in_Windows_10_sub)

Comment: Do you move the mouse and then the cursor moves after you have finished moving the mouse?

Comment: Hey do you mean `AMD Radeon R9 200 series`? Because the R9200 is a GPU model from them which is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

Your dad has an *ancient* graphics card, so it's  likely that is what is causing the delay. Try the same setup with a modern graphics card.

Another thing: when running 4k from HDMI, almost all modern GPUs (except very high end) only support 30 hertz in 4k mode (i.e. HDMI standard 1.4). 30 hz may not delay the input lag but it DOES make the mouse movement really jittery.
To get smooth mouse movement you do need 60 Hz. It's a huge difference.
NVIDIA has a setting in the control panel to output 60 hz at 4k which is basically a hack it does by reducing some color info, but it works and it really made the mouse smooth on my system when running if it wasn't for this I don't think I would be using 4k as the jittery mouse movement was really annoying. I don't know if AMD has something similar. If not I would highly recommend an NVIDIA card to run Windows in 4k.

I believe displayport doesn't have this issue, but both your video card and monitor would need to support it.

Comment: There is no way that a motherboard which supports AGP is capable of having 16GB of RAM. `AMD Radeon R9200` is probably a mistake and should be expanded to read `AMD Radeon R9 200 series`. Why do you recommend nVidia?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus read my post, I recommend NVidia for getting 4k@60hz without HDMI 2. NVidia has a special "hack" for doing this, when HMDI 1.4 only allow 4k@30Hz not 60Hz.This is huge for the mouse movement. I don't know if AMD has the same feature or not.